# charAt() not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, charat

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>
  document.write("some text");
  function change()
  {
    alert("function loaded");
    var text=[];
    text=document.getElementById("inname");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.charAt(0);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="inname">
<button onclick="change()"> convert </button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

I created simple HTML page to read a string and display the first character of that string, but its not working.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: `text` is a dom element, not the value of that element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, The [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) method returns the specified character from a **string**. So `text` must be a `string` not an DOM Object. ***To get the value of the input use `text.value`***

```js
function change() {
  var text = document.getElementById("inname");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.value.charAt(0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inname">
<button onclick="change()"> convert </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned the DOM object itself to the variable `text`, not the text value of the input.

You need to use the `.value` property of this DOM object to get the text value.

i.e. `text = document.getElementById("inname").value;`